# UITextView responds very slow in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a dynamic UITableViewController with one prototype cell. In this cell are 2 UITextViews. Each of them should be editable. If this should matter: the data comes from a json-file and exists in form of a NSArray. (I program in Swift, so the correct type is [[[String:String]]]).
My problem is when I tap on one of the TextViews the iPad seems to load a few seconds and during this time the main thread is blocked and nothing happens. Then the keyboard pops up and I can edit the text. After selecting the first of the TextViews I can fast switch between them. Even if the TextView resigns his firstResponder I can tap one of them and the keyboard opens very fast.
How can I fasten up the loading at the beginning? 
I tried to call

```
myTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
```

in the cellForRowAtIndexPah (only for the first TextView) and then the whole view loads like 4 seconds before it shows up..
I hope you understand what I mean. If you need any code to understand it better, let me know :)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT #1:

Class of the custom

```
class BeschreibungZusatzCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {

    var delegate: CellDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var titelTextView: CellTextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var beschreibungTextView: CellTextView!

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if titelTextView != nil {
            titelTextView.delegate = self
        }
        if beschreibungTextView != nil {
            beschreibungTextView.delegate = self
        }

    }

    var titel: String! {
        didSet{
            titelTextView.text = titel
        }
    }

    var beschreibung: String! {
        didSet{
            beschreibungTextView.text = beschreibung
        }
    }


    func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if text == "\n" {
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
            delegate?.cell(self, didChangeContentAtIndexPath: (textView as CellTextView).indexPath!, andSpalte: (textView as CellTextView).spalte!, toString: textView.text)
            return false
        }
        delegate?.cell(self, didChangeContentAtIndexPath: (textView as CellTextView).indexPath!, andSpalte: (textView as CellTextView).spalte!, toString: textView.text)
        return true
    }

}
```

(Sorry for some german names, they are not important to understand the code I think :)) So the cell has a delegate which is my TableViewController. And each of the two TextViews has a delegate as well which is the cell. So if the TextViews change their string, I can get a message in my TableViewController. I need that to save the changes.

Comment: It's a single cell, with a unique reuse identifier? My only guess is that there may be multiple cells? Some more code may help.

Comment: It's one prototype that is used for multiple cells who looks the same but have different texts in it.

Comment: Ok, how are you getting a reference to that text view?

Comment: The cell is a custom class. I copy the code if it in the question above :)

Comment: Try moving the becomeFirstResponder call *out* of cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Actually I don't want to call it. The user does not really has to open the keyboard at start. I just wanted to test if it would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `becomeFirstResponder` call into `didEndDisplayingCell`, or an alternate method. cellForRowAtIndexPath is for configuring your cell, not for performing UI-related tasks.

Comment: I don't want to show up the keyboard at start, that was just to test if that would be faster, but it isn't. I want to show up the keyboard if the user taps in one of these textFields..